# Why is the media concerned about the sharia and the treatment of women in Afghanistan, but not in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: media, human-rights, saudi-arabia, afghanistan

The media and Western leaders are talking a lot about the treatment of the women in Afghanistan [[1](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/sep/03/afghanistan-women-defiant-amid-taliban-crackdown), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treatment_of_women_by_the_Taliban), [3](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/08/20/asia/afghanistan-women-taliban-intl/index.html)] and the country's move towards the Sharia law [[4]](https://www.qwant.com/?q=Afghanistan+taliban+sharia&t=web). They are described as issues raising serious concerns.

However there is no such concern when it comes to Saudi Arabia. Actually the move made by the Taliban is nothing other than an imitation of what is already in place there. Women, when the country was founded (between 1920-1930), had no rights [[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_rights_in_Saudi_Arabia) and changes, like access to education, happened very slowly. Only recently, after long protests, they managed to get the permission to drive cars [[6]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_to_drive_movement).

Modern Islamic fundamentalism was formalised by scholars paid by the Saudi Royals who brought to prominence fringe sects [[7]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahhabism) while they were already in business with American and British companies. The application of the Sharia law in Saudi Arabia has been funded with oil money, and it was never a source of concern.

However in several other contexts the threat to apply the Sharia is presented with a lot more concern. Why such difference?

Comment: @FluidCode in the future please format links properly to make your text easier to read :)

Comment: "However there is no such concern when it comes to Saudi Arabia" - this is completely false and inaccurate. I've been reading about these very concerns, on a regular basis, for over 30 years and running.  -1 for a straw man proposition and for asking a "why" question about an inaccurately described situation.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I beg to disagree. While in Afghanistan it is clear that a backward model is imposed on the population by those in power in Saudi Arabia many articles point to a conservative population, which is hardly credible. The concern on the rulers imposing such policies is quite different.

Comment: @FluidCode - Both of those are inaccurate. In Afghanistan, it's pretty clear that the Taliban has a lot of broad, popular support - at least, moreso than the warlords that the West tried to prop up to rule the country. That's why they persisted and took over after several decades of active efforts to stomp them out. Articles I read all point to Saudi Arabia as a brutal, totalitarian, and exploitative society.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet The Taliban are still there because of continuing foreign support. All of them were trained abroad and many fighters are'nt even Afghan. Local popular support is another media fiction.

Comment: @FluidCode - No, it's not another media fiction. It's an indication that often-failed template of supporting complete garbage as an alternative to the regimes or groups we don't like will not win over the people. Saudi Arabia is a prime example of this, as well.  It's not about the Taliban gaining popular support because they are popular, themselves, but because they are deemed as less odious and corrupt than the warlords. Regardless, your claims that the odiousness of the House of Saud have been ignored or glossed over are simply not true.

Comment: Saudi Arabia is an important alie of the West in the region, this fact should be not forgoten in this context.

Answer (score 51):

It's a little disingenuous to say they're not concerned about it, as much as it is to use 'the media' to describe a highly textured and diverse industrial sector.

That said, the status of women in Saudi Arabia is well documented, frequently discussed, and that history in addition to the fact that Saudi Arabia is a foreign policy ally of the United States (and in many ways the U.S.'s foot-in-the-door to Middle East politics and international relations) makes running headlines about Saudi Arabia less of a draw for readers.

Because of the recent drama in Afghanistan, and the links to the 9/11 attacks, the Taliban is a good topic to drive sales of papers. The U.S. public is very interested in/afraid of the Taliban and [fear is a good driver of newspaper sales](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4121338) (including virtual news media)

So for the general public, stories that can feature the Taliban and affirm reader's sense of superiority are likely to sell very well.  Comparatively, Saudi Arabia's relationship with the U.S. makes the emotional response to the poor state of Women's Rights in that country more complex and complexity doesn't sell as consistently. (Media that markets itself to niche audiences have more coverage of these issues, though.)

It's important to remember that "The Media" doesn't care or not care about things. They simply produce a product and market that product to maximize sales.

Comment: Still does not explain why nobody notices that the Taliban are just going to enforce rules already in place in Saudi Arabia.

Comment: @FluidCode Plenty of people "notice" it; but that's different from reporting it as part of a current news event. Afghanistan's treatment of women is currently getting sharply worse; Saudi Arabia's treatment of women has not recently changed significantly.

Comment: @FluidCode I believe it does. First off, plenty of people (yourself included) notice this. It is a matter of constant discussion in policy, international relations, and women's rights circles. But if you're asking why sales behave in this way, that's probably a question for Psychology SE rather than here.

Comment: *It's important to remember that "The Media" doesn't care or not care about things. They simply produce a product and market that product to maximize sales.* That's a very cynical view that describes tabloids and "social media" much better than serious newspapers, for example. Journalists and editors actually care a lot about their work and the issues they cover, or else they would have become quantitative financial analysts or whatever it is people think they can make money fast(tm) with these days.

Comment: It is not disingenuous to describe a "lack of concern". Diverse as the industry may be there is widespread news from all major news providers of all formats on the treatment of women in Afghanistan. That is not true for Saudi Arabia. That is the difference that the original poster's question asks for a response to.

Comment: Whoops. I believe that because of the stronger links of Al Qaeda to Saudi Arabia, that’s where the media should have paid attention, not Afghanistan. But I am afraid I am not saying anything that has not been said 20 years ago

Comment: The funny thing is: The fact that Saudi Arabia is a US ally should make human rights violations, including women's, *more* newsworthy, shouldn't it? Why are we teaming up with known criminals? I mean literally *nobody* is surprised about human rights violations by Taliban; that's such a non-issue.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica In the same way that we should expect society to find excesses in police violence particularly shocking/unacceptable. In both cases what ends up happening is a subconscious reduction of the perceived credibility of those critics. Very easy to accept someone saying a stranger is problematic than to hear that of your own friend.  On philosophical principle, you're right though.

Comment: @Sneftel I don’t agree that there’s nothing new to report on the status of women in SA.  There were gestures at liberalization under MBS, but when women activists were too vocal about the issue of driving rights they were arrested and brutally tortured by the police.  This was given a vanishingly small amount of media attention in the US.

Comment: "and the links to the 9/11 attacks" You're talking about Saudi Arabia, *right*? Bin Laden was Saudi, as were 15 of the 19 hijackers, and Saudi Arabia was the biggest source of funding for al-Qaida. The rest of your answer is good, but this seems to be a very weak argument for Afghanistan.

Comment: @famargar It apparently hasn't been repeated enough, though. If you ask people where the 9/11 highjackers came from, many will answer Irak, Afghanistan or Iran.

Comment: @Sneftel, Saudis even improved slightly in the last few years, as in allowing women to drive and go to theaters. Not that their treatment of women is anywhere close to the ballpark of what's expected in the civilized world, but it's and improvement nevertheless.

Comment: @EricDuminil You are technically correct (the best kind), but Bin Laden is dead. The Taliban sheltered him extensively (it's arguably the only reason US forces landed in Afghanistan to begin with), and so now the media/headline value is on the Taliban, not Bin Laden.

Answer (score 36):

This question is starting out from a false assumption, that the media does not regularly cover, mostly in a negative fashion, events in Saudi Arabia concerning both sharia and its treatment of women.

Those of us who follow international news closely have all read of articles about the subject, ranging from [driving restrictions](https://www.caranddriver.com/news/a35090601/saudi-activist-prison-women-drive/), to [chaperone enforcement](https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2016/feb/15/tammy-bruce-when-starbucks-meets-sharia/) , to [passport issuance and travel conditions](http://edition.cnn.com/2009/WORLD/meast/07/10/women.saudi/) (male relative has to approve), to capital executions (beheading by sword, no less).

#### What is true is that, *right now*, the media is covering Taliban activity more than Saudi Arabia.

- **The Taliban takeover is fresh and hot news**.  Covering Saudi Arabia just means repeating the same things, unless something new starts happening.  It is normal, not nefarious, that the media focuses more on current, new, events.  Rather than past events, which they have covered.
- Talibans are an avowed US/Western enemy.  While Saudi is an avowed US/Western ally.  More on that later
- Saudi Arabia has a, deeply flawed, legal system.  But it at least pretends to have one at least and enforce rules.  Taliban, right now and in the 1990s had more of what we could call summary justice.
- Saudi has kept itself pretty distant from Taliban win, probably not wanting to trigger another round of Western electorate disapproval.  I don't think it figured in the list "nations now opening relations with Taliban" asked about in a recent question. (Note that, historically, Saudi has had a lot to do with the mess, since they were 1-1 matching US funds to support Mujahideen in the 80s and were part-controlling, with Pakistant the spigot on who would get the funds.  Being Wahhabi-approved was at least as important as battlefield competence).  So if Pakistan has been a direct sponsor of the Taliban, Saudi has been indirect, at least historically.
- Recently Saudi has, to a limited extent, granted some more freedoms to women.  Whether that is a sincere move by MBS, whether it is to support their intent to make Saudi's economy less oil dependent by attracting foreign investment, whether it is to muzzle the power of the religious establishment, or whether to deflect attention from the prince's unfortunate tendency to order *journalists offering critical coverage of Saudi* dismembered in their embassies is up for debate.

Doubtless, Saudi Arabia's rather toxic role in world affairs and [malign Wahhabi influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahhabism#Criticism_by_other_Muslims) on one of the world's major religion, Islam has not been sufficiently acted upon by Western governments.  A number of reasons come to mind:

- Saudi Arabia has an outsized capacity to influence the oil market, both by its reserves, its capacity to ramp up production and its ability to do at very low prices (Saudi oil is really cheap to produce).  That has long suited the West.  Whether it will be as influential when we decarbonize is unlikely.
- Saudi Arabia imports tons of Western weaponry, sadly probably one of the best ways to "influence" Western foreign policy.  It is also anti-Iran aligned, giving it massive dollop of goodwill from the Iran-obsessed USA.
- Saudi Arabia has, in the past, generously assisted Muslim immigrants in Western countries.  For example, [some?/many?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_propagation_of_Salafism_and_Wahhabism) of the mosques originally built in France for its large Muslim population were built with Saudi money.  For more details, you could read [here](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2019/05/01/islam-made-in-france-debating-the-reform-of-muslim-organizations-and-foreign-funding-for-religion/).

All of this can translate to less negative press coverage than might be appropriate, true.  And Western civil society seems quite a lot more distrustful of Saudi Arabia than they believe their governments should be.  Canada's government for one gets criticized for still exporting weapons to it.

**But to claim that there is limited negative press coverage of Saudi Arabia looks like an attempt to discredit.**

p.s. on top of that, Saudi regularly gets criticized for other activites such as:

- [famine in Yemen](https://www.cnn.com/2021/03/10/middleeast/yemen-famine-saudi-fuel-intl/index.html)
- [economic incompetence](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-52588971)
- [military incompetence](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20191010-what-is-behind-saudis-military-failures/)

p.p.s.  Nothing against the Saudi people.  They are, like all too many in the Middle East, ruled by a rather oppressive and incompetent lot (as in similar cases, their government suits Western interests just fine).  The current situation is a reflection of their repressive government and its symbiotically-linked clergy, not necessarily of their culture.  It would be great if they managed to govern themselves, in the sense of the heady expectations of the early days of the Arab Awakening.  Past experience would lead many of us to be somewhat dubious of the likelihood of a positive outcome, but that's still something to hope for.

Comment: Do you have some sources to link to prove your answer?

Comment: So glad you asked.  Are you disputing any particular one?  This is all pretty well know stuff.

Comment: Actually not. All the articles I read about the situation of the women in Saudi Arabia told that those harsh rules were not imposed from above, but desired by a backward society, which is hardly credible. I never read an article or heard a politician making a statement with the same alarmed tone. I would really like to see an article published on mainstream media with such tones.

Comment: Not really, no.  Saudi may not be the most enlightened place in the universe, but the current situation is largely due to the House of Saud striking a devil's bargain with the Wahhabi sect.  "We'll back your religious repression if you say we rule by the grace of God".  That's also well known and well covered.

Comment: Also stuff like executions of women https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/saudiarabia/8952641/Saudi-Arabia-execution-of-sorcery-woman-condemned.html or https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-45270224

Comment: Saudi Arabia did contribute to the construction of a handful mosques (mostly large ones) but it is not the most active foreign country in that respect and funding by foreign governments is actually less important than most people think. Whereas Turkey, Morocco, and Algeria directly send or employ imams in France, Saudi Arabia has been careful not to be heavy-handed about this and the Salafi mosques are not necessarily those that received direct funding from Saudi Arabia.

Comment: I think you should drop the Google Search images. I paged through the "news saudi women rights" results and there were 104 of them. It displayed "130,000,000 results" up to page 10, then "104 results" on page 11. When I told it to "repeat the search with the omitted results included", it said there were 150,000,000 results but there were actually 429. There are probably more than 429 pages containing the search terms in their multi-trillion-page database; my point is they aren't actually searching them, they're just guessing a number, probably based on independent frequencies of each word.

Comment: @benrg Yeah, you're right.  I'd like to keep them around but if they're meaningless, so be it.  Bing seems to be better, you can keep on following them 2 by 2, next time I use a search to indicate interests I'll use them instead.

Answer (score 13):

What's happening in Afghanistan is "news". During the US occupation of Afghanistan, the Afghan government had been making progress in its treatment of women. With the Taliban taking over, much of this progress is expected to be reversed. This is a sudden, dramatic change for the worse, so it's natural for it to receive lots of coverage in the media, especially since both the past progress and the recent reversal are direct consequences of US actions.

What's going on in Saudi Arabia is just the status quo in that country, it's not news. When there are changes, the media covers it -- when they gave women the right to drive 2 years ago, that was big news.

As an analogy, in the past few weeks, there have been a couple of incidents of coyotes biting children in my town (a Boston suburb), and this made the news. I'll bet there have been many incidents of dog bites during the same period, but none of them were in the newspaper.

It's also the case that women have better lives in Saudia Arabia than Afghanistan. Even before the recent action of the Taliban, female literacy in Afghanistan was only 17%, versus 45% for men there ([reference](https://borgenproject.org/tag/literacy-rates-in-afghanistan/)), and 93% in Saudia Arabia ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_rights_in_Saudi_Arabia)).

> Georgetown Institute for Women, Peace and Security ranks Afghanistan as one of the worst countries for women. ([reference](https://giwps.georgetown.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/WPS-Country-Ranking.pdf))

In the above ranking, Saudia Arabia is 99th place, while Afghanistan is 152nd out of 153 countries ranked. The list is from 2017, before the Saudi reforms of Mohammed bin Salman.

Comment: The same comment I wrote in eckes's answer applies here. I did not mean a difference in the amount of news we see today, but a difference in the tone.  In reports about Afghanistan it is clear that those rules are imposed from above. In reports about Saudi Arabia not, many articles state that this is due to a backward society which is hardly credible. Also in this case the rules are imposed from above.

Comment: I've added more information about the differences in women's rights are better in Saudi Arabia than Afghanistan. Not great, but still justification for more coverage of the latter.

Comment: Barmar (the web page does not like your name with the at symbol)  Please see the comment in the answer to Acccumulation

Answer (score 8):

Two answers to this, one cynical and the other practical. Cynical answer first.

**Cynical answer**

The media is biased, always has been, always will be. The bias can be small, but it's noticeable and there. That's why [conservatives read Fox News and liberals read Huffington Post](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/61702).

Another way to have bias is to decide what to report on. It's why when Crimea voted to join Russia, Western newspapers focused on how the referendum was not free or fair and interviewed Crimean Tartars, while Russian newspapers focused on how Crimeans are overwhelmingly in favor of joining Russia & demonstrations in other parts of Russia in support of Crimea joining Russia. It's why Western newspapers use the word '"annex" and Russian newspapers use "ascension". Both report facts, but both push a different narrative.

You see something similar with Saudi Arabia & Afghanistan. Western newspapers want to push the idea that the Taliban are evil people who repress women, hence they report extensively on Taliban atrocities and interview women who do not like Sharia law. Note they don't interview women who are happy to live under Sharia law or think Sharia is correct (I am sure some exist, since there are women who wear full-face veils even in countries that don't require it). Western newspapers don't want to push the narrative that the Saudi Arabian leadership are evil people who repress women, hence they don't report it (at least not right now).

**Practical answer**

Ultimately the newspaper needs to earn money, and to do that it needs to report on what its readers want to read about. Sometimes an event is so major that everyone has to cover it, but other times there is room for discretion. This is when editors of newspapers can be biased (above in the cynical answer).

On the other hand, you can be sure that the editors are also monitoring what their readership are doing. If the articles on Afghanistan generate a lot of clicks (see [example](https://www.axios.com/2022/06/02/ukraine-russia-war-social-media-interest) for the war in Ukraine), then they are in demand, and the newspaper would quite sensibly keep reporting on Afghanistan.

In practice the two factors kind of intertwine. If a Western newspaper were to start reporting that [Afghans are actually happy to live under the Taliban](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/68118/),* then because most Western readers want to believe the Taliban are evil, the readership would move *en masse*, and the paper would lose money. Equally, the editors of the newspaper want to believe the Taliban are evil, so they are already biased to keep up with kind of reporting. It's an unholy alliance that keeps the media reporting on what it's reporting.

The upshot is people become polarized because they read different newspapers; there are plenty of examples worldwide.

*I have no idea if this is true, but given that answer, it's possible.

Answer (score 6):

As has been pointed out, Taliban treatment of women is "news", in that it's a new, ongoing event. To go into detail, "news" can have an influence on decisions. In this case:

- It's ongoing about how many Afghan refugees to settle in the US and where. There's some push-back. Stories about brave young Afghan women encouraged by American national guards-people now huddling in fear will have an impact on those refugee issues.
- It can be political criticism (of either the President who pulled out, or the one who made a deal to pull out, or the US in general). Once again America broke its promises to loyal allies.
- It may influence the Taliban. In theory they've promised to be slightly less brutal, and are going to be asking for international aid -- maybe a few can be pressured to decide that pictures of happy girls going to school, not leaving bloody footprints, is worthwhile.
- It's analysis -- a big US goal was women's rights. After 20 years of trying to change the culture, did it work, even a little? Or are regular Afghanii men welcoming women finally being put back in their place?
- It may change US policy, which is currently in flux. More drone strikes, fewer? Recognize the Taliban? Send in more special forces? Horror stories may force the US to take a harder line.

Answer (score 2):

Because the only country that can reasonably supply the US with the oil it needs is the Saudis. Hence the US has to skirt around the human rights violations as to not antagonize a nation that it is more dependent on than what they would care to admit.

Afghanistan has no oil and nobody depends on it for anything. So widespread criticism be they fair or not has no political consequences. The US sells arms to the Saudis but occupy Afghanistan. Politics has always been a dirty game.

Comment: US is net exporter of oil https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=42735 and the import was not all that important for decades.

Comment: Besides which, why would "the media" care about offending a political ally? I don't remember them being soft on them during the Oil Crisis in the 1970s.

Answer (score 2):

The direction and the frequency of the changes:

From the western viewpoint, women rights in Saudi Arabia are only improving in the last 6 or 7 decades. Major events (like women in SA being allowed to get various education degrees, to drive different types of vehicle or women getting important government or business management positions) are discussed in the media (well, at least in the media I read). But these are not a groundbreaking headlines.

On the other hand, women rights in Afganistan is much more complex and convoluted topic for the same timespan.

Afganistan moved from sharia-style women treatment to nearly european-style (during the better part of the Soviet invasion), sharia again, great deal of improvement during the last 20 years of US-influenced government and once more going to sharia right now.

Such a profound changes in Afganistan make news much more than the slow, but steady development in Saudi Arabia.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of your question is, quite simply, false. While it's true that there are many restrictions on women in Saudi Arabia, it is not true that they have *no* rights, nor is it true that the Taliban imposes no restrictions that Saudi Arabia doesn't impose. Furthermore, while the Taliban has suggested that they will not be as harsh as when they were last in power, there is concern about how far this moderation will extend. When they were last in power, girls were banned from education, and from being seen by female doctor. And since women weren't allowed to be doctors, that meant a serious lack of medical care for women and girls. BTW, the sentence "Women, since the country was founded (between 1920-1930), had no rights" is not grammatically correct. "Had" is simply past, but "since" refers to a period of time. Thus it is ambiguous as to whether your sentence should be corrected to "At the time of the founding, women had no rights" or "Women have not had any rights [at any point] since the founding".

Comment: +1. The difference in coverage could easily be justified by e.g. comparing the share of female students in SA vs. share of female students in Afghanistan the last time that the Taliban were in power. Just judging from statistics the track record in Saudi Arabia is probably not stellar (certainly segregation leads to some problems?) but not comparable at all to Afg in the late 1990s.

Comment: Thank you for the grammar correction. Actually what I wanted to say is that the rights and the strictness of the rules when the Saud regime was established were similar to those in Afghanistan now that a new regime is taking power. Of course almost one century has passed since Saudi Arabia foundation and some changes happened, but they are very small changes.

Answer (score 1):

The psychological effect of loss of freedom is much more traumatic than the effect of never having had it.

It is patently human to mourn a loss.  A society which, for any reason, managed to advance to a state in which freedoms are prevalent will be viewed as upcoming.  The ones in which freedoms are lost will be viewed as tragic.

## This isn't new.

This approach has always been part of the human condition.

Just picture yourself living in an ancient Greece with its many city-states.  Sure, they all have slaves.  But most people don't mourn the tragedy of the fact that there isn't another way to organize society.  They accept it.  Not accepting the only known way to live leads to depression and inability to function.  So they accept it.

But what happens when one city hears that another one was destroyed and its inhabitants became slaves?  That's viewed as a great loss by those inhabitants.  Not because it contributes to the numbers of slaves that exist.  But **because it *is* a loss.**

The same happens in the modern world when freedoms are rapidly lost in some far-away countries.  Some people don't care.  But some people empathize with their loss just as they would empathize with loss of life.

Answer (score -1):

In general:

Objecting to change (Afghanistan) tends to be seen as more pressing and more justified than pushing for change (Saudi Arabia).

Whether or not it *actually is* either more pressing or more justified is beside the point. The point is just that people tend to see it as such.

#### It's "more justified"

Humans are rather strongly biased towards maintaining the status quo.

People will often make arguments like "it's just part of their/our culture" or possibly "they/we are happy with the way things are". It is at least true that *some* are happy with the way things are, which can make it much harder to change it.

#### It's "more pressing"

Change is *a thing that's actively done*.

**If you push for change:** You can try to push for change to happen at a specific point in time, but if you fail to cause change, or if you just try to push for change as soon as possible, then you're just left needing to *continue* pushing for change until change happens (or you give up). In some cases you may be able to put enough pressure on those who need to make changes to cause change quickly, but in other cases you may just be left needing to continue pushing for change *indefinitely*, often with little to no clear signs that you're making progress nor any indication of how long it will still take to achieve your goal. It can be a pretty frustrating and unproductive position.

Movements that push for change tend to benefit greatly from specific events. If something bad happens that supports the need for change (like a woman being treated poorly as a result of these laws, in a way that differentiates it from what commonly happens there), or if a step was taken towards making the change ultimately desired (like women being given the right to drive), this can draw a lot of media coverage and help motivate and grow the movement.

**If you object to change:** If someone *else* tries to change something, you can object to it when they try to change it. You've succeeded if they stop trying to change it for the moment. If they try again to change it later, you can object again. It's a much more reactive position, typically with a deadline of some sort, and not just something you have to continue doing indefinitely until you succeed. If they do successfully change it, and you continue objecting, then your position becomes one of pushing for change, in which case the point above applies.

---

All of this would still apply even if they're trying to change it back to the way it recently was.

Answer (score -5):

Since Afghanistan is a majority muslim country, Sharia law would be implemented whether the Taliban was in government or a regime approved by the West. The question is, not "the country's move to sharia law", but the interpretation thereof.

Although restrictions on women have been reported, such as not being able to drive alone, the coverage lacks nuance. For example, the Princess Nora bint Abdul Rahman university, based in Riyadh, is a university wholly dedicated to womens education and has around 34 thousand students with 3,500 teaching staff and 2100 administrative staff. It's worth recalling that quite a number of the colleges in Oxford and Cambridge are womens only (Newnham college in Cambridge still is). That Saudua Arabia is advancing womens rights under its interpretation of Sharia is much less commented upon - the attitude being that these countries are already 'backward'. It's this lack of understanding that hinders progress in the relationship between the West and Islamic countries. The West already see's itself as 'advanced' - not only in technology, but also morals.

Further, Saudia Arabia is much less in the news given that until recently there was a war going on in Afghanistan as part of the US sanctioned war on terrorism since 9-11. Of course, quite a number of the 9-11 terrorists were from Saudia Arabia, in fact 15 out of the 19 hijackers were from there. That little fact seems to have got lost in media brohouha as well as the fact that Saddam Hussein's regime was well known to be secular and chary of Islam and moreover, it was well-known that he had no weapons of mass destruction. In fact, the USA in the immediate aftermath had drawn up serious plans to use nuclear weapons in Afghanistan according to the testimony of a senior foreign policy advisor of the German chancellor at the time until persuaded that this would be a disastrous route to take, even more disastrous than the route they did take.

Comment: The assumption that a country will adopt the Sharia just because the majority of population is Muslim is not supported by the facts.

Comment: @Fluidcode: If it isn't supported by the facts give me an example.

Comment: Tunisia and Turkey dont really use Sharia (despite Erdogan in Turkey).  No one lost the plot about the 15 hijackers in any brouhaha btw.  Nuclear weapons in Afghanistan?  Please provide hard sources, as it makes zilcho sense to nuke dispersed rebels in a countryside, *purely at a military level*, let alone PR level.  -1.

Comment: @Italian philosophers 4 Monica: Turkey has recently begun imposing islamic finance laws in finance, and whilst under the ruling AKP party, alcohol has not been banned, it has become increasing expensive. Personally, I think Turkey is a special case, as Attaturk completely secularised the country and the public sphere after the loss of the Ottoman empire. Bangladesh is another country that has a secular constitution but its family law is sharia based, includimg marriage, divorce, alimony and property inheritence.

Comment: @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica: You are making unsubstantiated assertions which aren't supported by the facts ...

Comment: @MoziburUllah As you van see by this [Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_of_Sharia_by_country#Map) most of the muslim countries either do not apply the Sharia or apply some rules without the strict Saudi interpretation. Another example to see how uncommon is that extreme interpretation is the overview of [alcohol bans thoughout the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_with_alcohol_prohibition)

Comment: @Fluidcode: I picked one country from Africa, which according to your map, does not practise sharia or practise it lightly. I chose Senegal, its the Western most country in Africa, geographically speaking. According to this [blog entry](https://scholarblogs.emory.edu/islamic-family-law/home/research/legal-profiles/senegal-republic-of/) by Professor An-Na'im at Emory University, that whilst legal system is based upon the French civil law (their former colonial masters, with independence in 1960), their family law, prior to  the enactment of the family code in 1972, family relations were ...

Comment: @Fluidcode: ... governed by Christian, Islamic (and hence sharia) law as well as customary law. The enactment of the family code in 197w was to create a more uniform law which includes sharia. For example, polygamy is permitted with upto four wives but legally, they must be treated equally and fairly. This is definitely part of ordinary sharia law even though it is also part of the family code. Here, sharia is implicit. It's definitely *not* French. Thanks for the map, it was eye-opening. However, I think when digging down to the detail, ...

Comment: @Fluidcode: ... a much more nuanced picture comes into focus where sharia does play a role, even where the map says it plays a very limited role.

Comment: "Sharia law would be implemented whether the Taliban was in government or a regime approved by the West." Really? Is there Sharia law in Kosovo?

Comment: AFAICR there were some comparisons in Western troops/capita in Kosovo vs Afghanistan (like an order of magnitude IIRC). So that kinda illustrates "approved by" vs merely tolerated by the West given what it would take/cost to get something really "approved by the West".